# Any "smart" way to disable telemetry of a web application on OS/hardware level? Any specific guide/tool recommend if we use linux and lnmp env

Tags: web-application, data-leakage, sensitive-data-exposure

Let's say we know as a fact that a php web application baked in telemetry to collection data.  Without scanning through the codebase, any quick hack tool that we can force the telemetry become useless given that we have full access the hardware running locally.  (if we can treat telemetry as data-leakage and sensitive-data-exposure?)

Comment: Figure out the mechanism and disable it. There's countless ways, and what's trivial to block depends on what your application requires to run. If the *wanted* and *unwanted* functionality is sufficiently close, it may be nearly impossible - if you don't simply comment out the offending code...

Comment: Use a firewall to limit outgoing connections from your system to the minimum needed for the system to work, i.e. restrict to things like automated updates etc. This not only prevents telemetry phoning home but also can prevent attackers to retrieve their payload in attacks like log4shell. This will not work if the telemetry is collected locally and then queried by accessing specific URL in the application - in which case you need to restrict access to all but the expected URL inside your server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Any specific guide/tool recommend if we use linux and lnmp env.

Comment: @Maxfield: Just use iptables/nftables for limiting outgoing traffic, which is the builtin firewall. The recommendations are the same as for any system hardening - telemetry is just another kind of unwanted communication.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, but during installation we need to open some ports, then block all ports?

Comment: What connections need to be allowed at which stages of setup an running really depend on the requirements of the applications running on the system. But if you intend to prevent telemetry during operation it is sufficient to add the restrictions after the installation.